# Indenting continuation lines with Artistic Style

Tags: java, astyle

Artistic Style indents these lines in a Java source file:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
    .test()
    .full()
    .value();
```

like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
.test()
.full()
.value();
```

Is there a way to get a more sensible indentation?

I am using Artistic Style 2.05.1 (latest version) with no options:

```
astyle < Test.java > Beautified.java
```